# jQuery - how to add table rows from the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a table that should be populated from result of an ajax call. The table is defined as:

```
<table id="resourceTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th th:text="${propB}" />
            <th th:text="${text}" />
            <th th:text="${description}" />
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        // contents to be inserted here  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I call the url directly on the browser, I get the expected result:

```
[{"value":"value","text":"text","description":"description","propA":"propA","propB":"propB"}]
```

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var trHTML = '';
        $(function () {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                trHTML = $('<tr>').append(
                         $('<td>').text(item.propB),
                         $('<td>').text(item.text),
                         $('<td>').text(item.description)
                );
            });
            $('#resourceTable').append(trHTML);
        });
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }
});
```

I know the data object exists, but I can't render the table.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use developer tools to see what data is bringing back. Also check this: dataType is json so the value you receive back, if it is a json, it already should be the json object, no need to parse it. Also I would append to the tbody tag instead of the table.

Comment: If data is indeed in the form you describe, it should be throwing an error when you try to `$.parseJSON(data)`.
If you are using Mozilla Firefox for dev (dunno if it works with other browsers), I know it's no longer *recommended* but I strongly recommend using Firebug for checking console logs and errors regarding javascript and ajax. It is no longer allowed, after Firefox 47 I think, to install it but that yellow *bug* has been a life saver for me and I don't really care for the new, not always better ;), alternative Firefox Developer Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the

```
data = $.parseJSON(data)
```

By specifying dataType:'json' in your ajax request, the returned object is already a javascript object parsed from the returned json. And BTW, if your server does return json as content-type header, then you should not even need to specify the dataType.